# Can't replace newline in string

Tags: c#, string

I am downloading strings from a SQL-DB, which are formatted like this:

```
What's green and has wheels? 
Grass, I lied about the wheels.
```

Now the problem is, is that I can't replace the newline in that string.

I tried:

```
myString = myString.Replace(System.Environment.NewLine, " ")
```

or `.Replace("<br />", " ")` or `.Replace("\r\n", " ")` or `.Replace("\n", " ")`

Comment: And how new line is encoded in your string?

Comment: If `String.Replace()` were broken we'd have known, so it must be your input. Inspect your input, print it character by character. **You** will have to isolate the issue.

Comment: What stops you to put a breakpoint in that line and check what is the effective char used for the newline?

Comment: did you try vbCrLf or vbCr?

Comment: @realnero, vbCrLf is the same as \r\n...

Comment: Have you tried `Replace("\r", " ").Replace("\n", " ");`

Comment: @ThomasLevesque, and vbCR?

Comment: @realnero, just '\r' is quite unlikely... IIRC, it was only used on old MacOS systems.

Comment: FYI: In the comments below, the asker points out a flaw in his code; that he was trying the replace on the wrong string.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The likeliest reason is that the newlines in the string are not `\r\n`, but just `\n`. Try to replace `\n` instead.

EDIT: try to get the bytes from the string and post them here so that we can see the actual characters.

```
var bytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(myString);
string bytesAsString = BitConverter.ToString(bytes);
```

Comment: "likeliest"... /me sighs. Why developers these days rely on guesses that much instead of checking what actual character there is? :-)

Comment: @Saphire: what if you take that string and check its bytes? What bytes are between `?` and followed `G`?

Comment: I checked the bytes. While I did that, I realized that I replaced the wrong string. So, after all. It helped.